# scroll animation trigger complete handler twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

This scroll animation trigger the complete handler twice..

```
$('html,body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop : 100
}, {
    duration : 600,
    complete : function(){
        console.log('scroll complete');
    }
});
```

If you remove either `html` or `body` in the selector the scroll animation loose its cross browser support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation is triggered on both elements, firing the complete handler for both elements.

You can use a promise to avoid it

```
$('html,body').stop()
              .animate({scrollTop : 100}, 600)
              .promise()
              .done(function() {
                  console.log('scroll complete');
              });
```

Comment: no.. If I remove one of the elements the complete handler is only triggered once :)

Comment: No.. the code is executed as posted.. If I remove one of the elements in the selector the complete handler is only triggered once.. If both elements are in the selector the complete handler is triggered twice

Comment: My thinking is off, I'm thinking of the scroll event, this is just an animation, and you should actually be using `window`

Comment: have tried with `window` and its not working.. but your solution works :)

Comment: @clarkk - Just tried it myself, and was sure that would work, as it's the `window.scrollTop` property, but for some reason it doesn't. The promise method would work, so use that.